# Custom theme woocommerce product detail page template not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am new in **WordPress** development, This question already asked but that not solve my issue.

I have create custom theme this my theme `folder structure`

[image]

In my custom theme product detail page css not working like this
[image]

this is my `function.php` code

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_woocommerce_support' );

function setup_woocommerce_support()
{
  add_theme_support('woocommerce');
}
```

> How to customize my won design in product detail page ?

Advance thanks...! sorry if am not asking correctly.

Comment: I think you have to copy all the woo-commerce templates into your them. I am not sure about that but I guess you can give it a try. Put, woo-commerce templates in a sub-directory of your theme. Name sub-directory as `woocommerce`

Comment: @BlueSuiter: I tried still no result

Comment: Check using source code view, Is your style resides on correct path?